# Can I import only a piece of html from an external file?

Tags: html, forms

I need to create an html file that contains only content within a form tag of another html file, and nothing else. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not with just html, no. html isn't a programming language. it has no "import" capabilities. You'd need server-side tools (e.g. php, SSI) or client-side javascript.

Comment: i think you could do it with iframe, but it's a bad practice.

Comment: You need a server side programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load html snippets after your main page loads using javascript. Something like this:

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**form.html**

```
<form>
    <input value="testing" />
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
var formUrl = 'form.html';

$(window).on('load', function(){
  $.get(formUrl, function(res){
     $('#container').append($(res));
  })
})
```

[Here is a working plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2TLhAsWvvIWcMwBwuFGW)

Comment: This is definitely functional, but I was looking for something that would bring a piece of html, like just the contents of a form tag, into another file. I am asking how to reverse the direction that the content is going in your example. How could I bring a piece of content from container in index.html into the contents of form.html?

Comment: What is the context? If it's not a user opening the page on a browser (i.e. no javascript available), then you'll have to do what others have suggested and use server-side languages to preprocess the files before responding to the request. HTML files are static just like text files unless they are (a) Rendered in a browser or (b) Modified by a server process before being sent back as a response.

Comment: Are you saying you want to scrape another HTML page, extract a particular section, and display it on your own page? If so, the basics are the same as my example but you'd have to parse the response text before appending it to your page.

Comment: Yes, the context is that I am trying to test some html form that exists inside of a scala template (page.scala.html). I am using the Jasmine framework, that has issues parsing this file. The only way I have gotten it to work is by copying the form into a regular html file and running tests on that. Which is bad, because it isn't the actual form that's being tested, and the second file has to be copied each time a change is made in the first, ect. I will do as you suggested, and parse the response text for the form. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Using webcomponents, it possible to [import HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) from other files. 
But this isn't widespread nor supported by all [major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) and maybe not what you're looking for.

You should really start by using a programming language like PHP, Ruby, Python or similar.